# Push Notification Custom Save Browser id in Database

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification

hi i am newbie to php and javascript and  i am working on a project of Push Notification for my website which will push a notification to the user when a news related to specific category is published on my website i am using following code and curl with the help of google documentation

```
<html>
<head>

  <title>Push Notification codelab</title>

  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Push Notification codelab</h1>

  <p>This page must be accessed using HTTPS or via localhost.</p>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  <button id="send">Send</button>

  <script>
    $("#send").click(function() {
      $.get("curl.php", function(data) {
        console.log(data);

      });
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

now i am wondering how to store a user's browser id or something so that it can send a notification to specific browser for specific category news.i am really looking forward to you guys to help me out for this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far to gather this information? This is not a "specific case only a few people would encounter", it is a common use case for php / javascript. The question does not suggest you invested any research effort in that case. Please read how to write a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing so-called as browser id, but you can generate a unique and store that in the `_COOKIE`, best combination of creating an unique id would be `MD5(USER_AGENT . SALTMIX_STR . IPADDR)`, this combination will generate a unique id for each browser and you can store that in cookie using `PHP` eg. `$_COOKIE["BROWSER_KEY"] = 'YOUR_UNIQUE_KEY'`

**EXAMPLE**

```
<?php
$generateUniqueKey  = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."!@#zYp04)+");
$_COOKIE["BROWSER_KEY"] = $generateUniqueKey; //Sets a key
echo $_COOKIE["BROWSER_KEY"]; //retrieves the set key
?>
```

Comment: can you show me a example how can i do this in my code

Comment: should i put this under $("#send").click(function() ? i also want to store this key in table

Comment: thanks you for the help i tried your code and console has following error SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal